# How to execute a cURL script from Moodle inside Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, localhost, moodle

I want to execute a cURL script that uses a Moodle webservice executed from curl_script.php

```
https://
mydomain.com/ws/curl_script.php
```

But wordpress redirects the file and shows the following message "Oops! That page can’t be found." 
And I don't know how to execute this file. What I'm missing?

[image: Hosting]

Content of curl_script:

```
    $user="admin";
    $password="Moodle15!";
    $services="moodle_mobile_app";


    $url = "mydomain.com/ws/login/token.php?username=".$user."&password=".$password."&service=".$services."";

    $ch = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Please provide more information. Are you able to open the port of the web service? Is there a firewall blocking the request? What is there in the script file? Have you tested this script earlier?

Comment: when I use localhost/moodle/curl_script.php works well. But the problem become when I upload on my webpage. I think there isn't any firewall. I'm goint to update the post with new information that you demanded of the content.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following rule in top of your htaccess file in order to allow execution of PHP files inside your moodle folder:

```
RewriteRule ^moodle/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
```

Comment: That didn't work. I updated my post and I added a picture where you can see the structure of my hosting. Maybe it's the permisions of .htaccess?

Comment: Could you add the actual content of your htaccess too?